# Find all the equivalence classes of $ℜ$

Tags: abstract-algebra, analyticity

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. Assume that $f$ has infinitely may zeros. We define the equivalence relation $ℜ$ on $G(f)$ via $(x_1,f(x_1))ℜ(x_2,f(x_2))$ if and only if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Here $G(f)$ is the graph of $f$.

My **question** is:

1) Find all the equivalence classes of $ℜ$.

2) Can we find an element $(a,b)∈G(f)$ such that the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ is finite? taking in account that $f$ is an analytic function.

Comment: Your prescription doesn't define an equivalence relation on all of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, since you've only given a prescription for points in the graph of $f$.

Comment: This still makes no sense. a) The equivalence relation is defined on $G(f)$, not on $G(f)\times G(f)$. b) An equivalence relation on $G(f)$ doesn't have an equivalence class for the real number $a$, which is not in $G(f)$.

Comment: @joriki: I have corrected those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence classes of $\Re$ correspond to the function values of $f$; there is one equivalence class for each function value of $f$, containing all points of the graph at which $f$ takes this function value.

Whether there are finite equivalence classes of $\Re$ is a roundabout way of asking whether there are values that $f$ takes finitely many times. There are analytic functions such as $f(x)=\sin x$ for which this is not the case, and analytic functions such as $f(x)=\mathrm e^{-x^2}\sin x$ for which this is the case.